# "Layout cycle detected. Layout could not complete." error in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight

I want to use Rad thermometer in my silverlight application. I took example from: [link text](http://www.telerik.com/help/silverlight/linear-gauge-create-thermometer.html)

I moved styles to external style file. If i use one control all is fine, if i add second thermometer on the page, i receive: "Layout cycle detected.  Layout could not complete." Where to find the source of the problem? In design mode all is fine.

Answer (score 1):

I would report this to Telerik as it's likely to be a bug inside the component. I remember the same happened several versions ago with the chart component under some conditions (they fixed it promptly).

I think there is no practical way for you to find the cause for this without access to the source code.